# Django-cms admin url 404 after language change

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I recently started learning `Django` & `Django CMS`, and was trying to change the language of my website from **English** to **Dutch**, I migrated over my pages using

```
Page.objects.filter(languages='en').update(languages='nl')
Title.objects.filter(language='en').update(language='nl')
CMSPlugin.objects.filter(language='en').update(language='nl')
```

In my `settings.py` I also changed `LANGUAGE_CODE` to `'nl'` and set my languages and CMS languages as follows

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ## Customize this
    ('nl', 'Nederlands'),
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'nl',
            'name': 'Nederlands',
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': False,
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    },
}
```

This works like a charm for the normal pages, but as soon as I try to open the admin interface I get the following error

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/nl/en/admin/cms/page/?language=en
Raised by:  cms.views.details
Using the URLconf defined in PinManagementSite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

sitemap.xml
nl/ admin/
nl/ ^cms_login/$ [name='cms_login']
nl/ ^cms_wizard/
nl/ ^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$ [name='pages-details-by-slug']
nl/ ^$ [name='pages-root']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, /nl/en/admin/cms/page/, didn't match any of these.
```

As far as I can see I configured it all correctly, but when I go to the admin pages it tries to route me through `/nl/en` instead of just `/nl/` and I can't figure out why.

For completeness I'll add my `urls.py` below

```
from cms.sitemaps import CMSSitemap
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from django.urls import include, path

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path("sitemap.xml", sitemap, {"sitemaps": {"cmspages": CMSSitemap}}),
]


urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("cms.urls")),
)

# This is only needed when using runserver.
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

Versions are `djangocms==3.8.0` & `Django==3.1.8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using only one language, so **don’t use i18n_patterns()**.

```
urlpatterns += [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
]
```

You are trying to access '**/en/admin/cms/page/**', but language **`en`** not added to your `LANGUAGES`.

So Django try adding default language prefix **`nl`** and redirecting to that url in your case '**nl/en/admin/cms/page/**'. In this case the **path** not longer matches with the admin path.

---

You can also try to add English in your `LANGUAGES`:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('nl', _('Nederlands')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
```

I tried your settings. Django CMS works fine with the same settings as yours. Be sure the page is not cached.

Comment: I changed my urls.py to have the re_paths in them, but that still doesn't solve the problem. I also tried the `include(admin.site.urls)` that you have in your answer but that crashed the server saying that passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer, yeah, we don't have to use `include()` for `admin.site.urls`, it deprecated since Django 1.11. I did not notice  `include()`  immediately in my answer.

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer, are you using custom templates? Can you show your template.

Comment: The templates are just what Django generates when you use djangocms’ automated setup, I haven’t changed anything in the project yet except for the language and making a page from the admin page back when it was still set to English

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer, I edited my answer. Django CMS works fine with the same settings as yours. Try to remove `i18n_patterns()`